# Add shortcode in my div

Tags: php, html

I want to add a shortcode in a div created by me in my theme

This is the div:

```
 <?php if(!is_home()): ?>

          <div id="cristi"><?php echo get_the_content(1); ?></div> 


  <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the shortcode:

```
[contact-form-7 id="54" title="Contact form 1"]
```

This is the link:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=19

Just look at this moment ...

What needs to change to run this shortcode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need the `do_shortcode()` function

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id="54" title="Contact form 1"]"); ?>
```

I have not tested your shortcode.